# Some Alt codes not working in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, alt-code

I'm using Windows 10 Pro v1903 and would be grateful for help with a problem that has been present for a week or so with alt codes. Having read various pieces of advice, I can confirm that

- Num Lock is off
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Enter method\EnableHexNumpad` has type REG_SZ and value data 1
- `Settings | Ease of Access | Mouse | Control your mouse with a keypad` has slider button to left hand side and says "Off"
- `charmap` brings up a nice character map which when I click on "é" says "Keystroke Alt+0233", which is a combination that *should* give that character but doesn't (see below)

Alt+0224 works properly in Notepad, giving "à"; it does nothing in Firefox or MS Word;
Alt+0232 in Notepad does the same as Ctrl-V, i.e. it pastes what's on the clipboard; in Firefox and Word it does nothing (this should give "è");
Alt+0233 does nothing in Notepad, Firefox, or Word (this should give "é") ;
Alt+164 works properly in Notepad, giving "ñ"; it does nothing in Firefox or Word.

Comment: What keyboard layout do you have set? if you use an International layout you can get all those just using dead-keys, rather than having to use alt-codes.

Comment: Works well for me. Note: To use `EnableHexNumpad`, you need enter "Press Alt,plus,hex-code,release Alt". For decimal input: "press Alt,0232, release Alt".

Comment: @Tetsujin - Settings | Language | Preferred language is normally "English (UK)".

Comment: I use UK language & toggle between UK keyboard & US International - this MS article tells you how to set it up & use. https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/keyboard-shortcuts-for-typing-accent-marks-over-letters-in-windows-10?from=Settings&OCID=LanguageSettings

Comment: @harrymc - The decimal codes worked up until recently. (I have a list taped to my laptop and used them a lot.) Decimal Alt 0233 works in none of the 3 mentioned programs now; hex Alt + 00e9 works in Notepad but not in the other 2 progs.

Comment: Does this also happen when [booting in Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)?

Comment: @Tetsujin - Thanks for this. I'm curious as to why you use UK and US International, rather than UK and UK International, or alternatively US and US International. I've now activated UKI, put it on toggle, and also discovered the delights of Unicode hex codes, not forgetting the "+".

Comment: UK because it's physically a UK ISO keyboard. US International because there isn't a UK International layout https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2PQG.png